# Does Project for the web supports integration with Azure Devops Services(Cloud)?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, project, ms-project, azure-boards

Does Project for the web supports integration with Azure Devops Services(Cloud)?

-I am trying to integrated Project for the web with Azure Devops Services, I am trying to add a new row to the roadmap and add a epic, I am successfully able to add the Epic to the project for the web, but when I am changing the end date in epic is Azure Devops, then the changes are not reflected in Project for the web, and the synchronization error popsup.

Does Project for the web supports integration with Azure Devops Services(Cloud)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a duplicate of a post to the Microsoft Answers forum. The question was answered on that forum (ref):
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/does-project-for-the-web-supports-integration-with/f0f81668-dfd5-496a-9f96-5ed3ab006342
John

Comment: Yes, I have raised that question in Microsoft Forum too